# Preventing selection of the same value in seperate comboboxes on a C# form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building a form application in c#. I have between 6-12 different comboboxes (varying depending on other options specific to this program, but that's beside the point), each with the same 6 selections.

What would be the easiest way to prevent a user from selecting the same item in more than a single combobox?

Comment: ASP.NET, WPF, WinForms? What .NET version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you were to just create a method to handle the SelectedIndexChanged event for the combo boxes, set them all up to use the same method, and do some quick validation, like so:

```
private void TestUniqueSelection(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
      var controls = new List<System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox>();
      controls.Add(...); // <-- Add all of your controls here.

      ComboBox changedBox = (ComboBox) sender;

      if (controls
           .Where(a => a != changedBox && a.SelectedItem == changedBox.SelectedItem)
           .Count() > 0)
           MessageBox.Show("Selected Option has already been chosen");
}
```

Obviously you could make it more efficient by having the List<...> be a private member variable and only set it up once, but I wanted to be succinct and understandable in the sample code.

Comment: I eventually used this in my program, and it's working, but for some reason, I can't get any code to run right after the messagebox (for example, something to set the combobox back to blank.)

Comment: Simple, just add a blank at the top of each one, and write: changedBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

Comment: Now that it works, I need to understand how it works. Mind running through that if()?

Comment: Sure; First we look through the list of combo boxes ("controls.Where") for any other combo boxes ("a != changedBox") where the user has selected the same value as the value they just changed the current combo box to ("a.SelectedItem == changedBox.SelectedItem"). If we find any ("if (....Count() > 0)") then we know we have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options that I can come up with off hand; preemptive and responsive.

@Steve has given a quick example of responsive (react to a select event an make sure it doesn't duplicate)

In a preemptive approach you call a method to remove the value from all other combo boxes on the form so that it can't be selected.

```
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace SO_Forms_Demo
    {
        public partial class ComboBoxes : Form
        {
            public ComboBoxes()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //do whatever else you want to do here....

                removeDuplicateValues((ComboBox)sender, ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString());
            }

//....Through ...//
            private void comboBox6_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //do whatever else you want to do here....

                removeDuplicateValues((ComboBox)sender, ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString());
            }

            private void removeDuplicateValues(ComboBox sender, string value)
            {
                //get all of the comboboxes in a collection
                List<ComboBox> comboboxes = this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().ToList<ComboBox>();
                foreach (ComboBox cb in comboboxes)
                {
                    if (cb != sender)
                    {
                        cb.Items.Remove(value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

once you have this inplace there are many ways to make it more robust (keep track of previous values and insert them back if changes are made, etc.) but this answers your basic question.

Comment: Seems like precisely what I was looking for. (I attempted something similar myself with no success.) I must be missing something though, because when implemented like above, it doesn't function as expected. No errors, it simply doesn't remove the value.

Comment: Well...It works on my machine :o) although I initially confused `SelectedItem` with `SelectedValue` and that didn't play.

Comment: @Cos Callis  Well, despite a lot of tinkering, it doesn't look like I'm going to get this working tonight. I'm going to go ahead and mark your post as the answer, seeing as how this was what I was looking for. Hopefully I'll figure out what the problem is!

Comment: @Cos, @Deadgnome; FYI... having "comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" through "comboBox6_SelectedIndexChanged" is completely unnecessary. Simply hook them all up to the same, single, method. Also, the proposed solution doesn't take into account the need to add the removed items back into the other lists when the selected value changes... which will make the solution a lot more complex... especially for someone who is having a problem simply limiting the selection to begin with.

Comment: @Steve, that depends entirely on the what @Deadgnome _wants_ to do. If the same handler will actually do what needs to be done then you are correct. But that requires you to _assume_ more than is in the OP.

Comment: @Cos, not really... you can hook up multiple event handlers to an single event... so, it really doesn't require any assumptions. Even if he wanted to run other, unique, stuff for each drop down, he could still do that easily. I really don't see where you're coming from with that one.

Comment: @Steve yes you **CAN** hook up multiple event handlers to a single delegate, it _DOES_ **REQUIRE** that you assume you want the same actions to happen when the those events occur.  If he _'wanted to run other, unique, stuff'_ then you might as well have separate handlers. In the present case, if I want an "are you sure" dialog when combobox1 has a selected index change, and I want to filter a grid based on the selection of combobox2 then I am better off with different handlers. Since OP didn't specify, I didn't read 'into' (_assume_) the question, and just dealt with OPs question.

Comment: @Cos, I think you're really off the beaten path man. And you're the one who is making assumptions about what he wants/needs to do above and beyond what he mentioned. Maybe he is subclassing the comboboxes, and calling the method ".OnValidated()" on each one after this code runs; thereby letting him run different code for each, yet calling them all with a single line.... i'm just sayin'... I gave an "FYI"... just let it be.